# Convert record in csv file to string (what would show if opened as .txt file)

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

What I want should be very simple.

The csv file that I used:

```
"SamAccountName","sn","GivenName"
"PBrain","","Brain"
"JSteward","John","Steward"
"JDoe","John","Doe"
"SDoo","Scooby","Doo"
```

My code:

```
$baseFileCsvContents = Import-Csv $baseFile

$baseFileCsvContents | ForEach-Object {
    $baseSameAccountName = $_.SamAccountName
    [String]$mergedLineInFile = $_ | Out-String

    Write-Host '$mergedLineInFile =' $mergedLineInFile
    Exit
}
```

The output:

```
SamAccountName                                  sn                                             GivenName
--------------                                  --                                             ---------
PBrain                                                                                         Brain
```

Expected output:

```
"PBrain","","Brain"
```

Can anyone help me? Please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a a bit more complicated then just piping an object to string. You have to evaluate each property of the PSObject representing a line in CSV and then convert the values to strings.

```
$baseFileCsvContents = Import-Csv $BaseFile
$properties = $baseFileCsvContents[0] | get-member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object Name | %{$_.Name.ToString()}
foreach ($item in $baseFileCsvContents) {
    $mergedLineArray = $properties | %{'"' + $item.$($_) + '"'} 
    $mergedLineInFile = $mergedLineArray -join ','
    Write-Host '$mergedLineInFile =' $mergedLineInFile
}
```